# Never listens to me

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What do you call it when others never listen to what I am saying or discredit my experiences and talk over me?

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of *belittling*? Or perhaps *rude*? Are you looking for a negative action on their part?

Comment: Mansplaining...

Comment: They treat you as if you weren't there.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore.  Everyone ignores me and my accomplishments.
(to be fair, this is more passive than your implied active "discredit").

Comment: Ignored sounds like I am claiming victim.

Comment: You would be subject to being ignored; feeling victimized by being ignored is an internal state not implied by the verb itself and could only be determined by context, I would think.  In some contexts being ignored would be a *very* good thing, as in "the gunman ignored me."

Answer (score 1):

Condescension is another good way to describe this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

[Disregard](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disregard) would be an appropriate word.

> Disregard means - "lack of consideration or respect"

So to disregard someone not only means to ignore but it also means to disrespect that person (by ignoring or abusing or back biting or belittling achievements..so the word disregard fits right in your context).

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, ignore, belittle, dismiss, overlook and neglect are all words that would be suitable to use for what you are describing.

From what you are describing, I would go for **disregard**.